# How to reference a zip file uploaded in an s3 bucket in your terraform lambda code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

I've working on a project in which the s3 bucket in aws is already created via console and the lambda code is already there as an object. I'm creating a terraform script in which I will reference that zip and then create a lambda function and publish it. Incase there's any change detected in the code (the code zip can be changed from console), then it should publish latest. How can I do that? Currently I'm getting errror-

```
module "student_lambda"{
source = "https://....." // I'm using a template which creates lambda function
handler..
s3_bucket = "SaintJoseph"
s3_key = "grade5/studentlist.zip"
source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("/grade5/studentlist.zip").etag
.....
}
```

My bucket structure

SaintJoseph -- bucketname

- grade5

  - studentlist.zip
  - subjectlist.zip
- grade6

Errors I'm getting in plan -

1. Error in function call - Call to function filebase64sha256 failed: open grade5/studentlist.zip: no such file or directory
2. The bucket key or source is invalid.

**Can someone please also help to let me know what to use like etag/source_code_hash, etc so that it only takes changes when zip file is changed and how to remove existing error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filebase64sha256` works only on local filesystem. To reference etag of an s3 object you have to use [aws_s3_object](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_object) data source. The source returns [etag](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_object#etag).

Comment: Oh okay, so does it mean that of I directly refer the s3 bucket with the name and s3 key like how I'm doing above, that won't work? Can you explain with an example of possible?

Comment: @MinYoongi Sorry, can't provide you with example.

Comment: Okay no issues, thanks for the reference, however when I checked the documentation, it's creating an s3 object resource. I don't want to create a resource since all that already exists, so not sure if this will work, still I can try it.

Comment: @MinYoongi Sorry, provide wrong link. The link should be to **data source**, not resource.

Comment: Can't you use checksum_sha256 call?
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_object